# Why visited pseudo-class of a tag is applied to not visited links?

Tags: html, css, tags, pseudo-class

Why link before visiting already has  purple color?Can you explain why does it happen?Below i am providing HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color:purple;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: yellow;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Mouse over and click the link: <a href="https://xjedi.com/index.jsp?com=ob&id=8271">XJEDI</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[I have link to Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnce5gm9/)

Comment: Because, according to your browser, you have already visited the site before. Search the browser history. In my browser the link is green.

Comment: For me, it doesn't. At first its's green. Then I click it, go to the page, then its purple. Then I go back to the main page - yes, it's still purple. I delete the visit from my browser history and go to main page - the link is green again =)

Comment: Thanks.Can i mark you answer as right?